# How to write a CompareTo method to compare string values in binary search algorithm

Tags: c#, list, binary-search, compareto, sortedlist

EDITED: (editd the binary search method)
I am using c sharp. I have a sorted list that has some values in it such as name and their quantity.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;
namespace InventoryManagementSystem
{
    public class Tool
    {


            public Tool(string name, int quantity)
            {
                this.Name = name;
                this.Quantity = quantity;
            }

            public string Name { get; }
            public int Quantity { get; }


        public  int CompareTo(SortedList<string, Tool> other, String name)
        {
            return; //not sure how to write this properly
        }
    }
}
```

//toolitems class

```
 public class ToolItems

    {


        SortedList<string, Tool> gardeningTools = new SortedList<string, Tool>();

 public void gardeningToolData()
        {
            Tool gardeningTool1 = new Tool("Garden gloves", 50);
            gardeningTools.Add(gardeningTool1.Name, gardeningTool1);

                    WriteLine("Please enter a name of the tool");
                    String user = ReadLine();
                    int number = binarySearch(user);
}

        public int binarySearch(String user)
        {
            while (low <= high)
            {
                mid = (high + low) / 2;
                if (gardeningTools.Values[high].Name.CompareTo(user) == 0)
                {
                    WriteLine("mid is: " + mid);
                    return mid;
                }
                else if (gardeningTools.Values[high].Name.CompareTo(user) > 0)
                    high = mid - 1;
                else
                    low = mid + 1;

            }
            return -1;

        }
```

Edited: My code works now except it returns the index 0 if the value is between first and last index of list. How can I get the exact index from the sortedlist depending on what name user search for?

In short all I am trying to do is when user enter some string value and if it matches in the sortedlist (which we search using binary search algorithm) we get the index of that value from sorted list and update the quantity of that specific value (If user chose 'A' and it is at index 0 ("A", 5) then we ask user for how many `A` you want to borrow and user say 2, so the quantity gets update to 3 now.

Comment: `if (gardeningTools.Values[high].Name.CompareTo(user) == 0)` <= Why not just use the `string` class `CompareTo` method?

Comment: I can try that, but could you please tell me how to write the CompareTo() method? So it can actually compare those two values

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use the string class CompareTo?

Comment: Nope. Because it doesn't makes any sense (to me, anyway) to write a `CompareTo` method that compares a `SortedList<string, Tool>` with a `string`.

Comment: I gave you an example in my first comment. Basically it's `Name.CompareTo(user)`

Comment: Why don’t you use builtin methods of SortedList such as if(gardeningTools.TryGetValue(user, out var tool)) { // you can update quantity here as tool.Quantity = ...; }

Comment: You can check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1 out. SortedList is implementing IDictionary<TKey,Tvalue>. Basically, your sorted list will have methods that IDictionary has.

Comment: @Nazim Could you please write how to update quantity? I didn't quite understand

Comment: @ikea before I can write how to do it, could you please confirm that Quantity property of Tool class is get only, you can't update it on the instance of Tool. Would you mind to add setter to it as well? Instead of `public int Quantity { get; }` it will be `public int Quantity { get; set; }`

Comment: @ikea Welcome to StackOverflow. Why are you implementing your own algorithm that searches the index of the key in `SortedList`? `SortedList` already contains a method [`IndexOfKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist.indexofkey?view=netcore-3.1) that implements such functionality. Method `IndexOfKey` uses binary search internally. Why not use this method? Or you simply can use an [`indexer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.item?view=netcore-3.1) to get an item by its key.

Comment: I am trying to learn algorithm internal working using small projects so I am doing that for practice by building tool management project.

Comment: It should be compareto of mid not high ==0 that returns mid.

If ct(mid) == -1 then low=mid else high = mid

Comment: @BobVale Could you please tell what line exactly you are talking about? I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

SortedList is implementing IDictionary. Basically, your sorted list will have methods that IDictionary has. You can check this link [Microsoft Docs SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1) out.

In your question, my understanding is you want to find your Tool object from SortedList and update its quantity. I am not directly answering your question about how to write `CompareTo` method but instead proposing alternative solution to how you can achieve your actual goal. Please find below sample code:

Slight change on your `Tool` class, added setter to `Quantity` property and removed your `CompareTo` method:

```
public class Tool
{
    public Tool(string name, int quantity)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And here your console app part how to find and update quantity with user inputs:

```
SortedList<string, Tool> gardeningTools = new SortedList<string, Tool>();

public void gardeningToolData()
{
    var gardeningTool = new Tool("Garden gloves", 50);
    gardeningTools.Add(gardeningTool.Name, gardeningTool);

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name of the tool");
    var toolName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter quantity of tools");
    var quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Ideally you should check whether user enters valid integer

    if(gardeningTools.TryGetValue(toolName, out var tool))
    {
        // You should check here whether you have sufficient quantity before decreasing quantity
        tool.Quantity -= quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, it's not a homework. I am just trying to learn how binary search work internally, but not able to figure out. I am just trying to learn tool system to borrow and stuff. I would appreciate if you could help me understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I've modified this so that I'm also answering how to implement compareto.

```
public class Tool : IComparable<Tool>, IComparable<string>
{
    public Tool(string name, int quantity)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int Quantity { get; }

    public int CompareTo(Tool other)
    {

        // You could manually compare rather than this
        // return this.Name == other?.Name ? 0 : this.Name < other?.Name ? -1 : 1;
        return string.Compare(this.Name, other?.Name);
    }


    public int CompareTo(string other) {
      return string.Compare(this.Name, other);
    }
}

public int binarySearch(String user)
    {
        while (low <= high)
        {
            mid = (high + low) / 2;
            switch(gardeningTools.Values[mid].CompareTo(user)) {
               case 0: // Found
                 WriteLine("mid is: " + mid);
                 return mid;
               case -1: // Mid is too small.
                 low = mid + 1;
                 break;
               default: // Mid is too high
                 high = mid - 1;
                 break;
            }
        // probably should also check that high and low != at this point
        return -1;

    }
```